# Building a DLL with MinGW and loading it with Python's ctypes module

Tags: python, dll, mingw

I am trying to build a C DLL which can be loaded within python using ctypes.windll.loadlibrary(...)

I can create a DLL and a client program all in C which work following the MinGW tutorial at http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs.

When I try to load the same DLL within python I get an error:

```
OSError: [WinErrror 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Can someone give me some idea as to what I am doing incorrectly?

Here are the files:

**noise_dll.h**

```
#ifndef NOISE_DLL_H
#define NOISE_DLL_H

// declspec will identify which functions are to be exported when 
// building the dll and imported when 'including' this header for a client
#ifdef BUILDING_NOISE_DLL
#define NOISE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NOISE_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

//this is a test function to see if the dll is working
// __stdcall => use ctypes.windll ...
int __stdcall NOISE_DLL hello(const char *s);

#endif  // NOISE_DLL_H
```

**noise_dll.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "noise_dll.h"

__stdcall int hello(const char *s)
{
    printf("Hello %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

I build the DLL with:

```
gcc -c -D BUILDING_NOISE_DLL noise_dll.c
gcc -shared -o noise_dll.dll noise_dll.o -Wl,--out-implib,libnoise_dll.a
```

The **python** code is simply:

```
import ctypes
my_dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("noise_dll")
```

and I get the error above: '%1 is not not a valid Win32 application'

I know the DLL is not completely wrong, because if i create a client file:

**noise_client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "noise_dll.h"

int main(void)
{
    hello("DLL");
    return 0;
}
```

and build with:

```
gcc -c noise_client.c
gcc -o noise_client.exe noise_client.o -L. -lnoise_dll
```

I get a working executable.  I have some understanding of all of what goes on in the code, options and preprocessor directives above, but am still a little fuzzy on how the .dll file and the .a file are used.  I know if I remove the .a file I can still build the client, so I am not even sure what its purpose is.  All I know is that it is some kind of archive format for multiple object files

I can ctypes.windll.loadlibrary(...) an ordinary windows DLL found in the windows/system32 without an issue.

One final point:
I am using 64 bit python 3.3.  I am using the version of minGW tat comes with the recommended installer (mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe). I am not sure if it is 32 bit, or if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 32-bit python - your DLL probably wasn't compiled as 64 bit code.

Comment: While this does load the DLL, it does not allow running the function inside the DLL, in this case, "hello".

It works when building the DLL under MSVC.  But it's not a complete solution for MinGW.